# ViewBag on ListBox gets empty data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, listbox, viewbag

I made a LINQ Statement to fill a ViewBag and display it on my View, however for some reason my ListBox displays empty so i saved the LINQ statement on a txt file to see if it was empty, but it has the correct data, so my question is:

Why my ViewBag is not Displaying on my ListBox in my View?

**This is my Linq Filling the ViewBag:**

```
foreach (var item in db.VENTA_PLATILLOS
                       .Select(v => new { Turno = v.Nombre_Turno, Total = v.Total })
                       .GroupBy(l => l.Turno)
                       .AsEnumerable()
                       .Select(z => new { Turno = z.Key, Total = String.Format("{0:$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00);Zero}", Decimal.Round(z.Sum(l => l.Total), 0)) })
                       .OrderByDescending(a => a.Turno))

{
    listadesumas.Add(string.Format("{{{0}, Total = {1}}}", item.Turno, item.Total));
}

//txt file to see if Linq Statemnt is filled correctly and it is
var json5 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listadesumas);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SumasTurno.txt", json5);

//Filling my Viewbag with my LinQ Group By Result
var grupos = new SelectList(listadesumas.ToList());
ViewBag.Group = grupos;
```

**This is my View ListBox:**

```
@{
    var group = (SelectList)ViewBag.Group;
 }

@Html.ListBox("Group", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Group, new { style = "width: 300px;" })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in your controller instead...

```
ViewBag["Group"] = grupos;
```

...and this in the view...

```
@Html.ListBox("Group", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag["Group"], new { style = "width: 300px;" })
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Avroh however i got this exeption at running it 
"No se puede aplicar la indización con [] a una expresión del tipo 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject'"

Comment: @ArturoMartinez That's odd, I always do it that way, and have never seen such an exception. Can you give more details of your set-up, such as version of VS, version of MVC, etc. Anything that might be relevant. Also, if you start a new ASP.NET MVC web site, and add a code line like that to the default controller, do you get the same exception?

Comment: @ArturoMartinez Just tried a new project, used code similar to yours, and it worked fine, so it looks like there is some issue with your project. Try creating a new one and copying the relevant bits over to see if you can either reproduce the problem in the new project, or get it working. Either way it should give you some insight. Looks like your code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your example as best as I could without knowing the underlying database table. I have not found an issue and found that it does render the option list correctly through a viewbag property containing a select list. So in this example, I stubbed in a string list for the underlying database table. In this example, I am able to populate the option list through the viewbag property containing the resulting a list. I have to wonder if your conclusion that it is not displaying is related to contents of the viewbag property "Group"

My example code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    List<string> listadesumas = new List<string>();
    var FakeDbTable = new List<string>() { "a.bc", "a.cde", "b.xyz" };

    foreach (var item in FakeDbTable.Select(v=> new { itemname = v })
            .GroupBy(l => l.itemname.Substring(0, 1)).AsEnumerable().Select(z =>new { GroupingValue= z.Key, Total=string.Format("count {0}",z.Count())}).OrderByDescending(a=>a.GroupingValue))
             {
        listadesumas.Add(string.Format(" result item {0}",item));
             }

    var grupos = new SelectList(listadesumas.ToList());

    ViewBag.Group = grupos;

    return View();
}
```

The view code

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    var group = (SelectList)ViewBag.Group;
}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.ListBox("Group", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Group, new { style = "max-width: 500px;" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Result shows as this:
[image]